# What is the Hermitian conjugate of the 4-vector momentum in Dirac equation?

Tags: special-relativity, conventions, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

I am quite confused about the Hermitian conjugate of the 4-vector momentum $p=(p^0, p^1, p^2, p3)$. **The confusion mainly arises when deriving the Dirac adjoint and the charge current probability.**

(1).Conder the adjoint Dirac equation:

start from the Dirac equation:

> $p_u \gamma^u \phi = mc \phi$

Taking the Hermitian conjugate of the Dirac equation:

> $(p_u)^+ \phi^+ {\gamma^u}^+ = mc \phi^+$

note that  ${\gamma^u}^+ = \gamma^0 \gamma^u \gamma^0$ and $\bar{\phi} = \phi^+ \gamma^0$.

**So now If $(p^u)^+=p^0u$**:

> $p_u\bar{\phi} \gamma^u=mc\bar{\phi}$

So we can obtain the Dirac adjoint equation:

> $\bar{\phi}(\overleftarrow{p_u}\gamma^u-mc)=0$

**while If ${p^u}^+ = -p^u$, we cannot get such the Dirac adjoint equation above.**

(2). Cosider the charge current probability:

Still start from the Dirac equation:

> $p_u {\gamma^u} {\phi}=mc{\phi}$

multiply on the left side by ${\bar{\phi}}$:

> ${\bar{\phi}}p_u {\gamma^u} {\phi}={\bar{\phi}}mc{\phi}$ -----eq(1)

Now again, taking the Hermitian conjugate of the Dirac equation:

> ${p_u}^+  {\phi}^+ {\gamma^u}^+ =mc{\phi}^+$
>   -->${p_u}^+  \bar{\phi} {\gamma^u} =mc\bar{\phi}$

Then multiplying on the right side by $\phi$

> $({p_u}^+  \bar{\phi} {\gamma^u}){\phi} =mc\bar{\phi}{\phi}----eq(2)$

**It seems that in order to arrive at the correct charge current probability $j_u=c\bar{\phi} {\gamma^u}{\phi}$, here we have to use ${p^u}^+=-{p^u}$ in eq(2) such that we can subtract eq(1) by eq(2) to cancel $mc{\bar{\phi}}{\phi}$ on the right-hand side and therefore reach the correct result.**

***Based on the derivation above, it seems there is some contradiction about ${p^u}^+$, which must be taken different values when deriving the Dirac adjoint equation and the charge current probability, i.e. ${p^u}^+=p^u$ for the Dirac adjoint equation; ${p^u}^+=-p^u$ for the charge current probability.***

Comment: @bistoal, try to understand the difference between Dirac adjoint and Hermitian adjoint. That will eventually help you to get the right road.

Comment: @AMS I know they are different.